# React Router v6 Route element cannot get Context value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-context

I'm using React `17.0.2`, react-router-dom `6.0.2` in my app right now.

I try to use react Context and Route to add authenticate on routes.

In `App.js` I can get value from AuthContext

```
...

const { authState, authReducer } = useContext(AuthContext);
    
<Routes>
    <Route element={PrivateRoute}>
         <Route path="/dashboard/*" element={<MainLayout />} />
    </Route>
    <Route>
        <Route path="/auth/*" element={<EmptyLayout />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={NotFound} />
</Routes>
...
```

but in `PrivateRoute` I got undefined

```
const {authState, authReducer} = useContext(AuthContext);

const {state, dispatch} = authState;
const ele = state.login === true ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
return <Route path={path} element={ele} />;
```

In this case, how could I get AuthContext in PrivateRoute?

Thank you

Comment: where are you creating the context? are you exporting it to the private route?

Comment: the context is create at AuthContext.jsx and import in `App.js` and `PrivateRoute`

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing JSX to the route's `element` props. The layout should render the private route component (*and outlet for nested routes*).

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/dashboard/*"
    element={(
      <MainLayout>
        <PrivateRoute />
      </MainLayout>
    )}
  >
    ... protected children subroutes ...
  </Route>
  <Route>
    <Route path="/auth/*" element={<EmptyLayout />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
</Routes>
```

`Route` components can be only children of a `Routes` component, so `PrivateRoute` cannot render one, it just needs to render out either the `Outlet` for the nested routes or the `Navigation` for the redirect.

```
const { authState } = useContext(AuthContext);
const { state, dispatch } = authState;

return state.login ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
```